# ECharts. How to customize charts for your data

Tags: charts, echarts

May be someone have experience with charts and i will be very appreciated for any advice. I use ECharts at my project and things were going well until I faced across the fact that i cann`t find way how to display my data. I want my chart to show "x" - 12 months, "y" - amount of something, each month has 5 group - companies, each company divided on 5 columns - statuses. On hover on group i want to see name of group - company and 5 statuses with numbers for each shows amount of it.   [I added jpg - example of what i want to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAMBr.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [this example](https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-examples/public/editor.html?c=bar-stack) at the ECharts website.

Note the `stack` property for each of the series, that's how you can stack and group your data.